# How to only alter WordPress query for frontend

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to alter the query ONLY on the frontend of the site to so some sorting using:

```
if (!is(admin)){
    add_filter('request','alter_query');
}
```

This works on the frontend just fine, but when saving posts the filter is still applied and won't allow the post to save. It appears as though it is still running the query. How can I stop the filter from running in admin on save?

The error is:

> {"code":"rest_post_invalid_id","message":"Invalid post ID.","data":{"status":404}}

When I comment out the filter backend works fine, but results are not as desired in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if( !is_admin() )` when modifying frontend queries. It determines whether the current request is for an administrative interface page or not.

Also, if you are modifying the main query then you should use `is_main_query()` as well.

[is_admin()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/)

[is_main_query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_main_query/)

Comment: Thanks. Tried adding that and the admin save still fails.

        if ( ! is_admin() && is_main_query() ) {
   $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
          $my_new_query = new WP_Query(); 
          $my_new_query->parse_query( $request );

Comment: @MrBrimm Have you tried only with `if( !is_admin() )` ?